# How can I tell MDN that a page has significant typos?

Tags: javascript

Does this [page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) have curly braces where they shouldn't be?

Comment: If you sign in you can edit it yourself, or you can [file a documentation issue](https://wiki.developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Getting_started#Option_5_I_found_some_wrong_info_but_I_dont_know_how_to_fix_it).

Comment: the entire mdn team has been laid off :( https://twitter.com/SteveALee/status/1293487542382333952

Comment: Yes. There's a formatting error. I tried to log in to MDN but I can't see where to enter my password anymore! It looks like you now have to have a GitHub or Google account.

Comment: The latest edit has messed up the formatting. See Archive.org to see what it should look like:- https://web.archive.org/web/20200809012557/https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MDN is a wiki, if you want to update it, click "Sign In" on the top right, and sign in using Github.

Go back to the page, there will be a blue button that says "Edit in Wiki".

Fix the problems yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Use this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Feedback

Also, not really a suitable question for Stack Overflow.